# Get the element where the sortable element is dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery's sortable plugin with two different lists.
I can drop one list's item to another list.

suppose I have two lists

```
List1-:  Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4

List2-: ItemList1, ItemList2, ItemList3
```

When I drag item2 over ItemList2 new list will be

```
List2-: ItemList1, Item2, ItemList2, ItemList3
```

I want to get ItemList2 (where the Item2 was dropped).

Here is my code

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="a">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 5</li>
</ul>
```

and jquery

```
 $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
 }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: What do you mean *"I want to get ItemList2"*..? When/where you want to access it..? Can you be more specific..?

Comment: I want to get the element over which the element is dropped

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample, You can access the item next to dropped element using the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) method. Inside the `receive` or `update` callbacks, the `item` property of second argument refers to the element which is dropped. You can access the next element like `ui.item.next()`.

```js
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  update: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.next().addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="a">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ItemList 5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Side note: [disableselection()](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/) is deprecated as of jqueryui `1.9` and the doc explicitly says:

*"Disabling text selection is bad. Don't use this."*

Comment: Thnx for the advice...but whenever I drop the element to another list it always sits at last

Comment: @Twix what do you mean *it always sits at last*..? According to the code you've provided it'll be placed where it is dropped... And this answer is based on the example you've provided.. please update the question with more info.

Comment: I dn know what the reason is but whenever I drop any item it goes at the last position of the list. Also I the `li` in second list are set to `display:inline`. otherwise the code is same as above

Comment: @tried adding `display:inline` for the `<li>`'s of second list, and it's not happening in the above snippet. Can you make an online demo which demonstrates your issue..? Maybe by adding a code snippet in question or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..?